# HTTP Error 500: Twitter API OAuth

Tags: apache, twitter, server, twitter-oauth

I am trying to connect to Twitter API using OAuth but I keep on getting `"localhost is currently unable to handle this request" HTTP ERROR 500`. Here is my code:

```
<?php
require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$consumer_key = "";       //left blank here intentionally.
$consumer_secret = "";
$access_token = "";
$access_token_secret = "";

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
print_r($content);
?>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: What php version do you have on your localhost? It may not have the minimum required 5.6.

Comment: @neptune i get `PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.10.4 (cli) ( NTS )`  when i run `$ php -v`

Comment: do you have both consumer_key and consumer_secret fields set?

Comment: yes..i set all the variables. Is this code running on your localhost server fine??

Comment: Cannot try it right now, but I will test it later today I hope. I used many times this library before without any problem.

Comment: yeah..please do let me know..i am kinda stuck here...

Comment: So, I installed the library with composer (`composer require abraham/twitteroauth`), changed the autoload path at the top to `require "vendor/autoload.php";` and it's working fine, getting the 220 code response.

Comment: It is working when loading directly the lib autoload too, with `require "vendor/abraham/twitteroauth/autoload.php";`. Check the path on your localhost. If you still get the 500 code message then there is something with your server side settings.

Comment: I have `autoload.php` file in `var/www/html/twitteroauth` so I guess path is correct and I am able to run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` from localhost....wat setting can be wrong??

Comment: I cannot help you with server setup issue, but I would search for this error  or ask about it adding more tags, like php, server or apache (or whatever server you have).